# How can I query unknown values from arrays in mongodb

Tags: pandas, mongodb, time-series, pymongo, ccxt

I am stuck and don't know exactly what to do I have a mongodb server that stores open high low close volume from a pandas dataframe I am trying to figure out how I can query every single document and get just the values without specifying the datetime stamp. I am new to mongodb and not entirely sure what to do

```py
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7d5aa984323fa67c2e9002"),
    "exchange" : "binance",
    "instrument" : "XRPUSDT",
    "timeframe" : "1d",
    "candles" : {
        "2019-09-06:0000" : {
            "open" : 0.25616,
            "high" : 0.25868,
            "low" : 0.24692,
            "close" : 0.2511,
            "volume" : 63377736.0
        },
        "2019-09-07:0000" : {
            "open" : 0.25115,
            "high" : 0.26285,
            "low" : 0.25009,
            "close" : 0.25993,
            "volume" : 53971229.0
        },
        "2019-09-08:0000" : {
            "open" : 0.25989,
            "high" : 0.26591,
            "low" : 0.2555,
            "close" : 0.26205,
            "volume" : 65033003.0
        }

 "_id" : ObjectId("5d7d74925bff7734c6c348a0"),
    "exchange" : "binance",
    "instrument" : "XRPUSDT",
    "timeframe" : "1d",
    "candles" : {
        "2019-09-06:0000" : {
            "open" : 0.25616,
            "high" : 0.25868,
            "low" : 0.24692,
            "close" : 0.2511,
            "volume" : 63377736.0
        },
        "2019-09-07:0000" : {
            "open" : 0.25115,
            "high" : 0.26285,
            "low" : 0.25009,
            "close" : 0.25993,
            "volume" : 53971229.0
        },
        "2019-09-08:0000" : {
            "open" : 0.25989,
            "high" : 0.26591,
            "low" : 0.2555,
            "close" : 0.26205,
            "volume" : 65033003.0
        }
```

for example i want the value for close in every document how can i query mongodb in python3 to just return something like 
["close": 0.2511, 0.25993, 0.26205,  0.2511, 0.25993, 0.26205]

and also get all timestamps from every document like
[2019-09-06:0000, 2019-09-07:0000, 2019-09-08:0000, 2019-09-06:0000,2019-09-06:0000, 2019-09-07:0000, 2019-09-08:0000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key (if you excuse the pun) to this is .items() which allows you to get the key, value pairs . After this, everything else is just dictionary operators which you can manipulate as needed.

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.pricedata.insert_one({
    "exchange": "binance",
    "instrument": "XRPUSDT",
    "timeframe": "1d",
    "candles": {
        "2019-09-06:0000": {
            "open": 0.25616,
            "high": 0.25868,
            "low": 0.24692,
            "close": 0.2511,
            "volume": 63377736.0
        },
        "2019-09-07:0000": {
            "open": 0.25115,
            "high": 0.26285,
            "low": 0.25009,
            "close": 0.25993,
            "volume": 53971229.0
        },
        "2019-09-08:0000": {
            "open": 0.25989,
            "high": 0.26591,
            "low": 0.2555,
            "close": 0.26205,
            "volume": 65033003.0
        }
    }
})
db.pricedata.insert_one(
    {
        "exchange": "binance",
        "instrument": "XRPUSDT",
        "timeframe": "1d",
        "candles": {
            "2019-09-06:0000": {
                "open": 0.25616,
                "high": 0.25868,
                "low": 0.24692,
                "close": 0.2511,
                "volume": 63377736.0
            },
            "2019-09-07:0000": {
                "open": 0.25115,
                "high": 0.26285,
                "low": 0.25009,
                "close": 0.25993,
                "volume": 53971229.0
            },
            "2019-09-08:0000": {
                "open": 0.25989,
                "high": 0.26591,
                "low": 0.2555,
                "close": 0.26205,
                "volume": 65033003.0
            }
        }
    }
)

looking_for = 'close'
for record in db.pricedata.find({}, {"candles": 1, "_id": 0}):
    for k, v in record['candles'].items():
        print (f'{k}: {v[looking_for]}')
```

Result:

```
2019-09-06:0000: 0.2511
2019-09-07:0000: 0.25993
2019-09-08:0000: 0.26205
2019-09-06:0000: 0.2511
2019-09-07:0000: 0.25993
2019-09-08:0000: 0.26205
```

Comment: I would recommend converting the timestamp as a key to an rval with a field name of `date` or similar.  This will dramatically simplify your queries on dates and date ranges.

Comment: thank you for the help one other thing is i tried this in another collection with a little more data and the data structure is the same i get .Traceback (most recent call last):  print(v[looking_for])
KeyError: 'close' even though the collection has the key. I get the desired data back plus that error at the same time

Comment: You'll need to add some error handling then; wrap the print statement in a try ... except and print k and v. This should help isolate the issue.

Comment: ok thank you that helped me figure out the issue i forgot the other collection i tried it on had a few documents with a different schema

Comment: Re the performance you could use a regex or similar to filter the input data.